# Connect to TM1 using XMLA

Tags: xmla, cognos-tm1

I'd like to connect to a IBM Cognos TM1 using XMLA, in particular using Adomd.Net.

Accoring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OLAP_Servers#APIs_and_query_languages TM1 supports XMLA/MDX, but I can't find any documentation about this.

What would be the format of the connection string?

Has anyone tried, and how did you get on?

Comment: maybe the wikipedia page is wrong (anybody can edit it). Did you got a feedback from IBM

Answer (score 1):

Connection string:

```
Provider=TM1OLAP.1;Data Source=%TM1 Server%
```

The TM1 Login box will appear, you alternatively can provide the "User ID" and "Password" variables too with the string (I even found location variable for the NT Servername, haven't tried it though).

Little resource:
http://www.bihints.com/tm1_sdk

Answer (score 0):

TM1 supports MDX including implementation of some custom functions, but it does not support XMLA. A few years ago, Cognos documented that XMLA support was on the way, but basically it never happened. You can use the legacy ADOMD library to connect to TM1 cubes - at one time it was quite popular in TM1 circles to do this in VBA. I've done this through .NET as well. However, there's probably some pitfalls to consider trying to talk to TM1 using ADOMD in .NET. TM1 has a number of APIs (C++, .NET, Java) which includes methods for issuing MDX queries to cubes and getting cell sets back.